# Building 0MQ under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, configure, zeromq

I'm trying to build and install the ZeroMQ libraries (2.1.11 cloned from GitHub) under Cygwin (on a Windows 7 system).

`configure` gives me this error message:

> configure: error: cannot link with -luuid, install the e2fsprogs
>   package

which persists even after I install e2fsprogs (1.41.14-1).

Is this a sign that ZeroMQ needs a real Ext2 file system? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the libuuid-devel package. (When getting a linker error about -lxyz, searching http://cygwin.com/packages for libxyz usually does the trick.)

Comment: ak2, thanks a lot, `make` is now running; and additional thanks for the search tip -- as you may have guessed, I don't get my feet this wet very often...